# trying to parse text and html from email over IMAP using MAIL::IMAPClient but text is hidden in parts and multi-parts

Tags: perl, imap

I can connect to the IMAP mail server easy enough:

```
 use Mail::IMAPClient;
 use MIME::Base64;
 use MIME::Parser;

  my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    Server   => '192.168.2.2',
    User     => 'xxxxxx',
    Password => 'yyyyyy',
    Ssl      => 1,
    Uid      => 1,
  );

  my $folders = $imap->folders
    or die "List folders error: ", $imap->LastError, "\n";
  print "Folders: @$folders\n";

$sfolder="INBOX.2012";

$imap->select( $sfolder )
    or die "Select '$Opt{sfolder}' error: ", $imap->LastError, "\n";

my @msgs = $imap->messages or die "Could not messages: $@\n";
```

However, the text and html I want is not easily parsed due to codes like this:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding:
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary="----------=_4F0F4830.7079357A"
Multipart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;   boundary="----=_Part_4487195_1184536749.1326753403034"
Multipart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:
Content-Type:multipart/alternative; boundary=--boundary_164442_d184e417-739f-
46d6-824a-6ea1846e79de
Multipart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;   boundary="----=_Part_3882878_23916831.1326509484032"
Multipart
Content-Transfer-Encoding:
```

I tried this but it only works on a tiny number of different encodings.

```
if  ($imap->get_header($msg,"Content-Transfer-Encoding")=~ /base64/i) {
print "\nMatch base64";
        if    ($imap->get_header($msg,"Content-Type")=~m/text/i )   {
         push(@mail,decode_base64($imap->body_string($msg)));
        }
        elsif ($imap->get_header($msg,"Content-Type")=~m/image/i )
        { print "\nImage detected"; }
        elsif ($imap->get_header($msg,"Content-Type")=~m/application/i )
        { print "\nApplication detected"; }
```

There are 7bit and 8bit variants and other encoding methods that contain the **html or text** I want for later use.  I successfully use decode_base64() to decode base64.  The worse ones to decode are the ones that contain multi-part codes.  I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel and there must be a library or module that can do all the heavy lifting for me.
Other content types such as .jpg,.gif, and .pdf should simply be ignored.  The multi-part emails contain at least 1 part that I an interested but many that are useless to me.

After further research this structure has some of the information I need but don't know how to get it out efficiently is another matter.

```
Dumping:$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'bodyparms' => {
                                  'boundary' =>     '----=_NextPart_002_BC64_7D688C1F.A2FF9BE0'
                                },
                 'bodyextra' => undef,
                 '_top' => 1,
             'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
             '_id' => 'HEAD',
             'bodysubtype' => 'mixed',
             'PartsIndex' => {
                               '1.3' => bless( {
                                                 'bodyparms' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodyid' => '<d9e26cc0-019c-4ac0-9b1e-9c9ac8424f52>',
                                                 'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                 '_id' => '1.3',
                                                 'bodysubtype' => 'jpeg',
                                                 '_prefix' => '1.3',
                                                 'bodysize' => '4808',
                                                 'bodytype' => 'image',
                                                 'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodyenc' => 'base64'
                                               }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                               '1.1' => bless( {
                                                 'bodyparms' => {
                                                                  'boundary' => '----=_NextPart_000_36AE_880DDD08.0A776E35'
                                                                },
                                                 'bodyextra' => undef,
                                                 'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                 '_id' => '1.1',
                                                 'bodysubtype' => 'alternative',
                                                 '_prefix' => '1.1',
                                                 'bodytype' => 'MULTIPART',
                                                 'bodystructure' => [
                                                                      bless( {
                                                                               'bodyparms' => {
                                                                                                'charset' => 'utf-8'
                                                                                              },
                                                                               'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodyid' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                                               '_id' => '1.1.1',
                                                                               'bodysubtype' => 'PLAIN',
                                                                               '_prefix' => '1.1.1',
                                                                               'bodysize' => '1971',
                                                                               'bodytype' => 'TEXT',
                                                                               'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'textlines' => '74',
                                                                               'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodyenc' => 'quoted-printable'
                                                                             }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                                                                      bless( {
                                                                               'bodyparms' => {
                                                                                                'charset' => 'utf-8'
                                                                                              },
                                                                               'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodyid' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                                               '_id' => '1.1.2',
                                                                               'bodysubtype' => 'HTML',
                                                                               '_prefix' => '1.1.2',
                                                                               'bodysize' => '23364',
                                                                               'bodytype' => 'TEXT',
                                                                               'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'textlines' => '331',
                                                                               'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                                                               'bodyenc' => 'quoted-printable'
                                                                             }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' )
                                                                    ],
                                                 'bodyloc' => 'NIL',
                                                 'bodylang' => 'NIL'
                                               }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                               '1' => bless( {
                                               'bodyparms' => {
                                                                'boundary' => '----=_NextPart_001_EA96_2BF8DEDE.32622D51'
                                                              },
                                               'bodyextra' => undef,
                                               'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                               '_id' => 1,
                                               'bodysubtype' => 'related',
                                               '_prefix' => 1,
                                               'bodytype' => 'MULTIPART',
                                               'bodystructure' => [
                                                                    $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1.1'},
                                                                    bless( {
                                                                             'bodyparms' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodyid' => '<5dff39db-e81c-4410-be75-8662564fd328>',
                                                                             'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                                             '_id' => '1.2',
                                                                             'bodysubtype' => 'jpeg',
                                                                             '_prefix' => '1.2',
                                                                             'bodysize' => '14406',
                                                                             'bodytype' => 'image',
                                                                             'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodyenc' => 'base64'
                                                                           }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                                                                    $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1.3'},
                                                                    bless( {
                                                                             'bodyparms' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodyid' => '<717f2ef4-f795-4d1c-87cc-283c9b0a59b0>',
                                                                             'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodydisp' => 'NIL',
                                                                             '_id' => '1.4',
                                                                             'bodysubtype' => 'gif',
                                                                             '_prefix' => '1.4',
                                                                             'bodysize' => '2912',
                                                                             'bodytype' => 'image',
                                                                             'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                                                             'bodyenc' => 'base64'
                                                                           }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' )
                                                                  ],
                                               'bodyloc' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodylang' => 'NIL'
                                             }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                               '1.2' => $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1'}{'bodystructure'}[1],
                               '1.1.2' => $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1.1'}{'bodystructure'}[1],
                               '2' => bless( {
                                               'bodyparms' => {
                                                                'name' => 'BKD-7361945220.pdf'
                                                              },
                                               'bodyid' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodyextra' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodydisp' => {
                                                               'attachment' => {
                                                                                 'filename' => 'BKD-7361945220.pdf'
                                                                               }
                                                             },
                                               '_id' => 2,
                                               'bodysubtype' => 'octetstream',
                                               '_prefix' => 2,
                                               'bodysize' => '47540',
                                               'bodytype' => 'application',
                                               'bodyMD5' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodystructure' => [],
                                               'bodylang' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodydesc' => 'NIL',
                                               'bodyenc' => 'base64'
                                             }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' ),
                               '1.4' => $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1'}{'bodystructure'}[3],
                               '1.1.1' => $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1.1'}{'bodystructure'}[0]
                             },
             '_prefix' => 'HEAD',
             'PartsList' => [
                              1,
                              '1.1',
                              '1.1.1',
                              '1.1.2',
                              '1.2',
                              '1.3',
                              '1.4',
                              2
                            ],
             'bodytype' => 'MULTIPART',
             'bodystructure' => [
                                  $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'1'},
                                  $VAR1->{'PartsIndex'}{'2'}
                                ],
             'bodyloc' => 'NIL',
             'bodylang' => 'NIL'
           }, 'Mail::IMAPClient::BodyStructure' );
```

As you can see none of the values are guaranteed to be part of every part on the PartsIndex and some them are nested.

variable of interest for each PartsIndex item:
bodytype
bodysubtype
bodyenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using a couple of prebuilt modules but they had too many dependencies and was hard to work with.  This solution adds no dependencies beyond the original.  I also had issues with the dependencies for libMagic, see above, and I did not want anyone who uses my program to have to deal with that issue either.

You have to call decode twice once for the main parent, and again for each child.  Since this $imap->get_bodystructure($msg); contains all the information you need why add dependencies where none are needed.  It took many many hours to figure out how to decode it manually, but it was worth it.

You can add whatever decoders you want to the decode() subroutine.  I only need to decode the text/html and base64 encoded versions there of.  The IMAPClient functions give you a list of all parents and children so you don't have to go making a list by yourself.  The tricky part is you can have any number of parent each with any number of children, but only the children contain useful data.  The parents can be ignored, since many of their values are blank,undef, or 'NIL' (literally).  In fact a vast number of variables have the value of 'NIL'.  Even ones that the email client could have answered for the user like bodyMD5 and bodylang are USUALLY equal 'NIL'.  Due to the overwhelming use of 'NIL' parsing and using other fields may prove futile.  Depend on your imap server and the people you recieve email from you mileage may vary.

If you have further questions leave a comment.

```
 use Mail::IMAPClient;
 use MIME::Base64;
 use MIME::Parser;

sub decode  {
($process, $imap) =@_;
if ($process->bodytype eq "TEXT") {
   print "\n Text SubType:".$process->bodysubtype;
   if ($process->bodyenc eq "base64") {
        return decode_base64($imap->bodypart_string($msg,$process->id));
        }
   elsif (index(" -7bit- -8bit- -quoted-printable- ",lc($process->bodyenc)) !=-1  ) {
        return $imap->bodypart_string($msg,$process->id);
        }
print "\n==========Insert new decoder here============";
print "\n".$imap->bodypart_string($msg,$process->id);
print "\n=================================================";

}

return "";
}

#insert your login code with credentials here


$imap->select( $sfolder )
or die "Select '$Opt{sfolder}' error: ", $imap->LastError, "\n";

my @msgs = $imap->messages or die "Could not messages: $@\n";


foreach $msg (@msgs) {


my $raw = $imap->message_string($msg)
    or die $imap->LastError;

$struct = $imap->get_bodystructure($msg);


#MULTIPART is a container designation and does not contain anything useful by itself.
#However it will still process all of the children that have content
if ($struct->bodytype ne "MULTIPART") { print "\n BodyEnc:".$struct->bodyenc();}

$rDecode=decode($struct,$imap);
#do not insert blanks.
if ($rDecode ne "" && (length($rDecode)>2)) {push(@mail,$rDecode); }


foreach $dumpme ($struct->bodystructure()) {
if ($dumpme->bodytype() eq "MULTIPART") {next;}

$rDecode="";
$rDecode=decode($dumpme,$imap);
#do not insert blanks.
if (($rDecode ne "") && (length($rDecode)>2) ) {
push(@mail,$rDecode); }


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse mail messages with [Courriel](http://p3rl.org/Courriel):

```
use strictures;
use Mail::IMAPClient qw();
use Courriel qw();

sub walk_parts {
    my ($obj, $callback) = @_;
    if ($obj->is_multipart) {
        for my $part ($obj->parts) {
            walk_parts($part, $callback);
        }
    } else {
        $callback->($obj);
    }
}

my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
    …
) or die $@;

my $folders = $imap->folders
    or die $imap->LastError;

$imap->select('INBOX')
    or die $imap->LastError;

my @messages = $imap->messages
    or die $imap->LastError;

for my $id (@messages) {
    my $raw = $imap->message_string($id)
        or die $imap->LastError;
    my $email = Courriel->parse(text => $raw);
    walk_parts $email, sub {
        my ($part) = @_;
        my $content = $part->content;
        my $type = $part->mime_type;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was downloading, compiling, and installing dependancy and then I got this as part of LibMagic:  Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 163.
Can't link/include 'magic.h', 'magic'

Comment: This warning is harmless. Force-install the distro if you need to, or skip the tests.

Comment: Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/File-LibMagic-0.96-CGG5Ev
  No 'Makefile' created
, won't make
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Apparently Builder.pm depends on it.  There are 4 occurrences of failure due to the whole missing LibMagic thing.  I was able to force install it, but I don't know if it will work properly without LibMagic.

Comment: does this module return html or plain text that has been base64 encoded?  If it does I can decode it, if it does not that is a problem.

Comment: The method `content` as shown returns the decoded content. The method `encoded_content` returns the encoded content. Read the documentation: https://metacpan.org/module/Courriel::Part::Single

Comment: Can't call method "content" on an undefined value at imap.sh line 37.
my $raw = $imap->message_string($msg)
        or die $imap->LastError;
    my $email = Courriel->parse(text => $raw);
    my $text = $email->plain_body_part->content;
    my $html = $email->html_body_part->content;
   line 37 is the $text = $email line.  Also I never got LibMagic working so that could be an issue.  Could also be that I need to check if the message even has a plain_body_part. This method ->content_type(); might work assuming it is done for ever part of the message.  I got the html_body_part.

Comment: Does that mean we have to identify each message part and execute ->content_type() and then use the correct method based on the return value?

Comment: Yes, you need to checks which parts the message has. Use the method `parts` and related methods, read the documentation: https://metacpan.org/module/Courriel - [Open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your installation problem, provide the whole log with the error message.

Comment: for my $subpart ( $email->parts ) {
 $type=$subpart->content_type();
 $mime = $type->mime_type();
print "\n MIME:".$mime;
   if ($mime eq "text/html") {
    my $html = $subpart->html_body_part->content; }
else {
    my $text = $subpart->plain_body_part->content; }

the decode method now fails.  It seems the the subpart no longer inherit the plain_body_part or html_body_part functions. Suggestions?

Comment: You are correct. Call just the `content` method: `for my $part ($email->parts) { my $content = $part->content; my $type = $part->mime_type; }`

Comment: $email->is_multipart() = false What you said works fine.  When it is true then Can't locate object method "content" via package "Courriel::Part::Multipart" at imap.sh line 43.  I tried as_string and that does a raw dump that I would parse.

Comment: What? Courriel *is* the parser. I have edited the answer to add a generic callback subroutine that recursively iterates over the parts of an email message.

Comment: Can't locate object method "content" via package "Courriel" at imap.sh line 53.
my $content = $part->content;
That is was I got, and I double checked for copy and paste errors twice.

Comment: "content" is not the metheod of Courriel (anymore?). Now you can not call $callback->($obj) and get $obj->content. You should iterate over $obj->parts and call for each multipart part recoursive walk_parts. Even if $obj is single part, their parts() is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You need a MIME parser. Unfortunately, even then, you will need some normalization of your own, because there are multiple ways to represent the same data in MIME.

Comment: Perhaps link a MIME parser module that doesn't suck? (e.g: MIME::Fast - http://search.cpan.org/~makler/MIME-Fast-1.6/Fast.pod)

Comment: $struct = $imap->get_bodystructure($msg);   foreach $xx ($struct->parts) {  $imap->bodypart_string($msg,$xx) }  Will loop through the parts, but will not identify if the contents is HTML or TEXT or base64 encoded HTML or TEXT so it is not completely helpful

Comment: I am looking at both suggestions now to see which one I can actually figure out how to code.  I used the DataDumper module to dump the above structure, is there a way to get the data out without another module?